# gstreamer pipeline for streaming multiplexed h.264 and aac audio between two raspberry pi's

Tags: audio, video, streaming, raspberry-pi, gstreamer

I have been stuck on this for days now. I am trying to come up with a GStreamer pipeline that will stream h.264 video and compressed audio (aac, mulaw, whatever, I don't really care) over a single rtp stream. The problem seems to always be with the multiplexer. I've tried asf, avi, mpegts, Matroska and flv multiplexers and it seems they are all oriented towards files (not network streaming) and are therefore requiring header information. Anyway, here's my latest attempt:

gst-launch-1.0 -e --gst-debug-level=4  \
flvmux name=flashmux streamable=true ! flvdemux name=flashdemux ! decodebin name=decode \
videotestsrc ! 'video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=15/1' ! omxh264enc ! flashmux. \
audiotestsrc ! 'audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,rate=22050,channels=2,layout=interleaved' ! flashmux. \
decode. ! queue ! autovideoconvert ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false \
decode. ! queue ! audioconvert ! alsasink device="hw:1,0"

This pipeline removes rtp and simply feeds the decoder with the encoder. Also, this attempt uses raw audio, not encoded. Any help will be ***greatly*** appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. To stream video+audio you should use 2 different ports.
2. Using **rtpbin** element to manage rtp session

Example http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/tests/examples/rtp/server-v4l2-H264-alsasrc-PCMA.sh